# Django: templates don't see custom user fields

Tags: python, django, django-users

I have a custom `User` model in Django 1.6:

```
from django.contrib.auth import models as usermodels

class User(usermodels.User):
    sid = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="slug")

    objects = usermodels.UserManager()
```

In one of my templates, I have the following:

```
Welcome, {{ user.username }}: {{ user.sid }}
```

If the user is authenticated, this just displays as, for example, "Chris:" if the username is Chris. The custom field `sid` isn't shown! I've checked my tables and the user does have an `sid` stored. It seems that the template isn't getting my custom fields!

I've added my custom model as `CUSTOM_USER_MODEL` to my settings.

Comment: You shouldn't be inheriting from auth.User, but from auth.BaseUser. Doing it this way isn't your actual problem, but does introduce an unnecessary db call when fetching data.

Comment: Do you mean `AbstractBaseUser` or `AbstractUser`? I can't find BaseUser anywhere in django.auth.models.

Comment: I extended `AbstractUser` instead of `User`, and set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` rather than `CUSTOM_USER_MODEL` in my settings. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting your custom user model in the `settings.py` with `AUTH_USER_MODEL` as specified in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-user-model), not `CUSTOM_USER_MODEL`

Comment: This gives an error: `myapp.user: 'user_ptr' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.` I've looked around a bit but can't find a solution.

Comment: I'm using django.contrib.auth.get_user_model() to reference the user model, except in foreign keys where I'm using settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL as specified in the docs.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where that error comes from, however maybe try sub-classing `AbstractUser` as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user). It seems more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: These two things together fixed the issue. Thank you!